# Buscar cambios dentro de una misma tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo una tabla histórica de cliente en sql server con los campos:

- CodigoCartera (a donde pertenece al cliente)
- DNI (Identificador)
- NombreCompleto (nombre del cliente)
- InicioDatetime (fecha de inserción del registro)

y quiero realizar una consulta para saber cuando al cliente lo cambiaron de cartera en sql server, por favor ayuda

Comment: bueno no es complicado, se me ocurre que añadas dos campos más para seguir tu trazabilidad, el fin datetime y otra columna que sea el activo (valga la redundancia, cuando tenga una fecha fin por lógica el activo será 1 , por ejemplo si es un campo en bit).

Comment: Que versión de SQL tienes?

Comment: @MrDonPh0x sql server 2014

Comment: La pregunta está incompleta. Deberías de exponer un ejemplo de lo que tienes y un ejemplo de lo que quieres obtener. A priori no parece nada difícil, pero depende del resultado que esperes, la forma de obtener los datos es completamente diferente.

Answer (score 0):

Para iniciar podrías ocupar esta query si es que tienes todas esas columnas de datos en la tabla TablaName y ? Es el DNI que te interesa revisar. Hay otras soluciones más elegantes pero dependerá de tus necesidades.

```
Select InicioDatetime From TablaName where DNI = ?
```